# "May be the best" or "May be a best" or "Might be"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe that something may be a very very good one. I would like to use "best" because I think it'd be really very good that I personally believe it's the best (just need more evidence).

Which should I say:

- May be the best
- May be a best
- Might be the best
- Might be a best

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Please provide more context. The best what? I formatted your question but could not presume to add punctuation. If you could, please complete with context, full sentences, and punctuation for each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you are talking about, and you will need to add a subject to the beginning of your sentence.

*It may be a best.* could be used if you are talking about something personal like a game score. For example you got a new great bowling score, and think it might be the highest you've ever gotten. In this case, "a best" is used as a short form of "a personal best".

*It may be the best.* could be used to talk about any situation where there are multiple candidates and one is believed better. For example, when discussing how awesome song #12 is on a CD.

In either of these cases you could substitute "might" for "may". You should keep in mind that "best" is a relative term. Something god awful can still be the best if its competition is worse.

Comment: @Aw Q - In this context, you can also use _could_ in place of _might_ or _may_, to express a degree of speculation. "That could be the best pie I've ever eaten," for example.

Answer (score 3):

When you’re talking about *the* thing that is better than every other thing in the world,
 use “***the*** best”. 
The phrase “***a*** best” implies that you’re talking about many “best” things, e.g.,

- A best practice (one of several very good practices; collectively, the best)
- A personal best. 
  The best that I have ever done (e.g., my fastest time in a race) is my personal best. 
  You, Archa, and Louis have your own personal bests.

Answer (score 2):

*May be the best* may be the best. ;)

Comment: -1.  I'm afraid this answer is Not An Answer; it appears to be more of a joke than an actual attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @snailplane It's a funny constructive answer.